# Confirm version of gdal that sf is using in R

Tags: gdal, r, sf, terra, rstats

In the {terra} package I can do this:

```
terra::gdal()
```

To confirm that {terra} has been linked to the correct version of gdal on my operating system.

Is there a similar command for {sf} ?

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are looking for [`sf::sf_extSoftVersion()`](https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/reference/sf_extSoftVersion.html) - it will list applicable versions of the "big three" - GEOS, GDAL & PROJ + few other specs of more niche use (gdal with geos and proj_h in use).